# Term for "Death by Lack of Water"

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know if the title is completely appropriate/applicable, but I guess it'll have to do until there's an edit.

---

So a if one dies of starvation, one dies from "suffering or death caused by hunger (New Oxford American Dictionary)". Is there a given term for "suffering or death caused by lack of water/thirst"? When one says "He starved to death", the meaning is "He died from hunger", but there's no term (at least to the best of my knowledge) for something like "He (word for died from thirst) to death)".

Comment: Which I am forbidden to see. I do not find /  
The Hanged Man. Fear death by water.

Comment: *Forthirst* is the archaic/obsolete English verb meaning "to die of thirst". Analogously, *forhunger* means "to die of hunger" (starve). The German translation of *forthirst* is the verb *verdursten*. Most English translation services appear to translate *verdursten* as "to die of thirst".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[*Dehydration*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dehydration?s=ts) might be the word you're looking for:

> He died from dehydration.

Comment: I feel like "dehydration" doesn't carry the force or drama, I suppose, of "starvation". For example, my coaches for sports say "Remember to drink water so you don't get dehydrated!", and that's not intimidating in the way that "starvation" is. However, I feel like "dehydration" can be used in the way I desire, though I'm hoping for a more fitting word, so I'll +1 you and if no better answer comes through, mark you as the answer.

Comment: @qegal The only related word I can think of would be *desiccation*, but I've never heard it used in the context of death.

Comment: @qegal: Umm, it may not sound all scary, but the reason coaches say that is because it's not unknown for athletes to drop dead of dehydration. [Here's a link to a recent example](http://www.wjla.com/articles/2012/07/parents-sue-montgomery-county-schools-football-coaches-over-son-s-death-77977.html).

Comment: Google for some pictures of people dying from dehydration, and it'll have more drama. The problem with the answer though, is that thirst isn't the only possible cause. People who die from heat exhaustion, diarrhoea or some types of kidney failure die from dehydration but not of thirst. Considering what a big killer diarrhoea is, it's probably the most common way to die from dehydration.

Comment: Rect after quick check. Yes, it's by far the most common way to die from dehydration, being one of the most common ways to die, at 2.6million deaths in 2009.

Comment: But the verb forms of *dehydration* and even *thirst* aren't as useful as that of *starvation*. *He starved to death* is perfect English. *He dehydrated/thirsted to death* sounds odd.

Comment: @kojiro Agreed. They're correct, but wouldn't be normal use. We'd normally just say "he died of thirst", and that would be that.

Answer (score 7):

> there's no term (at least to the best of my knowledge) for something like "He (word for died from thirst) to death"

Sure there is: "Died of thirst."  The phrase gets more than half a million hits on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22died%20of%20thirst%22&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmdo=1&biw=1316&bih=863&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=0e0kUPnuGI73qQHi0YHgCQ&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAA), and over 100,000 in [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ngrams&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmdo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22died%20of%20thirst%22&oq=%22died%20of%20thirst%22&gs_l=serp.3...7233.8199.3.8941.2.2.0.0.0.0.178.273.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.VkgALxmBHEs&psj=1&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=bd6fbbbb534f82e9&biw=1316&bih=863).

There's also "died *from* thirst", but *of* seems to be the [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died%20of%20thirst,%20died%20from%20thirst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) preposition.

If you really want a construction parallel to *starved to death*, though, you can simply say *[thirsted to death](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ngrams&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22thirsted%20to%20death%22&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmdo=1&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=O-8kULXuMIfgqAHHxoDYCQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=bd6fbbbb534f82e9&biw=1316&bih=863)*.

Answer (score 6):

from dehydration.
or if you want a longer form: of thirst.

Comment: How is _of thirst_ (eight letters, one space) longer than _from dehydration_ (fifteen letters, one space)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe not longer but more verbose.

Comment: @pasawaya How is it more verbose? It's the same number of words, they're just shorter words…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - My mistake, forgot the "from."

Answer (score 6):

To strictly fit the format, you could use *thirst* in its verb form. Hence

> He thirsted to death.

However, its use as a verb is relatively rare (indeed, it may well be one of those interesting cases where metaphorical use out-numbers literal, and *The athlete thirsted for Olympic gold* seems more natural than *I thirsted for a decent craft-brewed beer*, though both events described are as likely to occur).

For that reason it's technically correct, but sounds unnatural, and I wouldn't recommend it. I'd go for keeping *He died of thirst*.

*Hypernatraemia* caused by *dehydration* as given in other answers, are the most likely direct causes of what actually dealt the body its final irrecoverable blow, but there's no verb form of *hypernatraemia*, and *He dehydrated to death* has the same problems as *thirst* as a verb, and is imprecise: diarrhoea is the second biggest cause of infant deaths, and a common cause of older deaths, and then it is also death by dehydration, but not of thirst. Indeed, a patient of dehydration may find it hard to drink as much as their carers are encouraging them to, as while they are dying from dehydration, they are not thirsty.

Answer (score 5):

The proper medical term for dehydration is [*hypernatraemia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernatremia); however there is not a special term for the terminal state of this condition... one would say 'death from hypernatraemia'

> Hypernatremia is an electrolyte disturbance that is defined by an elevated sodium level in the blood.  Hypernatremia is generally not caused by an excess of sodium, but rather by a relative deficit of free water in the body. For this reason, hypernatremia is often synonymous with the less precise term, dehydration.

Comment: I think your edit makes clear what I already suspected -  *hypernatraemia* derives from Latin ***natrium**, sodium*. So it doesn't actually *mean* "dehydration" anyway - that's just one of the most likely *causes* of the condition.

Comment: dehydration causes a higher concentration of sodium; left untreated it results in death

Comment: Exactly - OP asked for a word meaning "death caused by lack of water", not "death caused by excess concentration of sodium". Like if he'd asked for "death caused by lack of air", the answer would be *suffocation*, not *asphyxiation* (which could include breathing pure nitrogen, or [some] carbon monoxide, etc.).

Comment: Your comment makes sense as long as you can demonstrate that it's possible to die from dehydration without suffering from terminal Hypernatremia.  Can you provide the evidence?

Comment: No, his comment makes sense because it's easily demonstrable that you can die from hypernatremia without dehydration though hypervolemic hypernatremia is rarer.
Ironically, one way it happens when in a desperate attempt to avoid terminal dehydration, people drink lots of sea-water. They are then hydrated, but hypernatremic, which increases the feeling of thirst leading them to drink more (they've already got to the point of desperation where the salt taste isn't putting them off) go into a coma and die from it, or from drowning (considering the scenarios where this comes up).

Comment: @JonHanna, this is a red herring; By your own admission, the subject is "then hydrated".  My point very simply is that you dont die "from dehydration", rather severe dehydration causes a fatal mineral imbalance known as Hypernatremia.

Comment: Yes, they're totally hydrated, and they die of hypernatremia. You can't say that the proper term for dehydration is hypernatremia, if you can die from hypernatremia and not be the least bit dehydrated.

Comment: You also can't say that you don't die from dehydration; if dehydration causes terminal hypernatremia, then it's both true that you died of hypernatremia *and* true that you died of dehyrdration. It's also true that you died of whatever caused the dehydration (e.g. thirst). If the dehydration was caused by diarrhoea, caused by cholera, caused by food-poisoning, then hypernatremia, dehydration, diarrhoea, cholera & food poisoning are all things it could be accurately said killed you.

Comment: @Jonhanna, you're knocking down a strawman.  The OP did not ask for a term for dehydration; he asked for a term for "death by lack of water"

Comment: And you gave him a word that means severe electrolyte imbalance, which can have nothing to do with a lack of water. In what way does that offer an answer?

Comment: @JonHanna, we already covered that ground and we disagree on the criteria for the answer.  The question is finished... may I suggest we agree to disagree

Comment: I have to clarify that dehydration and hypernatremia are not the same thing, though absolutely can occur together.  Some cases of dehydration result in severe hyponatremia which can also be fatal, such as severe gastroenteritis, I.e. dehydration. My apologies for being contrary.  I agree electrolyte abnormalities are a cause of death in dehydration.

Comment: @MikePennington: You are arguing sensitivity (hypernatremia includes all cases of dehydration) while Jon is arguing specificity (hypernatremia does not imply dehydration).  And Jon is correct, the word *hypernatremia* does not convey *lack of water*, so it is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Plus one. This is *why* you die from dehydration.

Answer (score 5):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/desiccation) defines *desiccation* as:

> the process or state of becoming completely dried up

However, it is probably used more often to refer to foods or landscape than to people. It is sometimes used to describe drying *after* death of an animal or person.

But the phrase *death by desiccation* has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Except in "poetic" usages, the process of *dessication* wouldn't really have gotten started until long after a person had died of dehydration.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't necessarily disagree.

Comment: I like this word but you're dead way before you desiccate.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking specifically for the format "He (word for died from thirst) to death)", then perhaps consider [shriveled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shriveled), though it isn't commonly applied in the context of humans.

Note that this actually means that he dried up from lack of moisture, which is basically the end result of staying thirsty for a long time. Normally, people would die way before that stage.

Answer (score 1):

We need to invent a verb for this that is used in the same way *starve* would be used.
***Thirsted to death*** is not bad but the parallel for food would be ***hungered to death***, not *starved to death*, so it is not ideal.

*Starve* is a verb used to indicate not just hunger but it also indicates that some damage is taking place to the body, the body wastes away. Someone suggested "death by desiccation".  Like *starvation*, it also is a slow process so how about

> He desiccated to death.

Although I think this is closer, it's still not ideal, as desiccation focuses on the end state, while starvation focuses on the suffering process. A word that focuses on the process would be **dehydrate**.  So the following phrase might work.

> He dehydrated to death

What do you think?  Sounds too strange?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As you may not be aware, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and your submission repeats other answers but does not really answer the question. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A single word or short term for "suffering or death **caused by lack of water**/thirst"? How about "dry up to death?"

> [Dry up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Dry+up?s=t): make or become completely dry.

For example,

> Fidgety [ a frog] had not escaped. Fidgety had not become a cat snack. He'd just crawled up into the [ceramic] turtle to hide. And while we searched and despaired and let all the water in his aquarium pond habitat evaporate, he had slowly starved and dried up to death. [source](http://www.backyardgiants.com/diary02.html)
>
> Four slugs dried up to death on my driveway. We are having a funeral for them at 
>   12 noon on Tuesday. It's a slug awareness day. Come dressed as a slug and bring your slime. [source](http://www.katu.com/news/local/Dozens-attend-funeral-for-bees-killed-by-insecticide-213772111.html?mobile=y)
>
> [dry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dry): *adj.* 9) desiring drink; thirsty. 14) dehydrated. *Random House Kerneman Webster's Dictionary, Ed. 2010*.

Answer (score -1):

dehydrocution, anhydrocution, dessicution, exsiccution

[Terminal dehydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_dehydration)

Answer (score -2):

In my mind I have always assumed if one perished, he died from lack of water.  I realize this is not a complete definition, but long ago decided it worked, and it does.  For me.

Comment: It might work for you, but is not a common definition of *perish*, so is not going to work for anyone else.