# What is the "thirsty" equivalent of "ravenously"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, food

When you eat something *very* hungrily, you can use the adverb *ravenously* to describe it. But when you drink something very fast in a similar way to quench your thirst, what adverb can you use to describe it?

*[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ravenously)* definition of *ravenously*:

> in an extremely hungry way: 
> *The children ate ravenously.*

Example sentence:

> He was so thirsty that he drank the water ______.

Comment: I suppose you could use [parchedly](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parchedly) , but I'm not going to. And your title indicates an adjective.

Comment: The college me would have suggested "Chug"

Comment: This is a great question! Some food for thought: If a common word doesn't come to mind readily, an obscure word, no matter how precisely it matches your meaning, will probably fail to resonate with your audience. In a case like this, I would try to paint the scene so viscerally the reader has to put the book down and get a glass of water before continuing. (I realize this is a writing and style comment, not language and usage, but I thought it relevant :)

Comment: There aren't as many grades of thirst as there are of hunger.

Comment: What's wrong with [*thirstily*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thirstily)?

Comment: ^ "Thirstily" doesn't have quite the same connotation as "ravenously" (but it does as "hungrily").

Comment: `Quaffed` would be my choice.

Comment: "Mama, I'm gonna thirst to death!" said the little girl (true story).  Sometimes it's not about the word you use, but how you juxtapose them.

Comment: Remember that ***ravenous*** actually means  *rapacious*: tearing at something as a **raptor** or a **rapist** might, to violate it violently. There is a sense of crude desperation. Just as [we have no analogue for “starved to death” for *thirst*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77770), here you’ll find no exact word the trades hunger for thirst.  So you’ll have to connote the desperate abandon with which the dangerously thirsty chug down water once finally available to them using some other aspect of that frenzied guzzling.

Comment: Very good point. I was just wondering whether there _was_ one.

Comment: Also **gushingly.** *To flow forth suddenly in great volume: water gushing from a hydrant.*

Comment: Doesn't *gushingly* usually refer to the manner of the liquid flowing out of the pitcher, not the manner in which one drinks it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't think there's a perfect word for this, but here are some suggestions:

**[insatiably](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insatiable)**

- This does not, of course, refer specifically to thirst, or to the action, but it does mean "incapable of being satisfied", which covers the motivation and thereby suggests the action.

**[voraciously](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voracious)**

- "having a huge appetite". Of course *appetite* typically relates to food, but one can have an appetite for anything: consider "a voracious reader". Interestingly, MW has this to say about the origin:

> Latin *vorac*-, *vorax*, from *vorare* to devour; akin to Old English
>   *ācweorran* **to guzzle**, Latin *gurges* whirlpool, Greek *bibrōskein* to
>   devour

Of course "[guzzle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guzzle)" specifically refers to drinking.

**[unquenchably](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unquenchable)**

- "quenchable" = to relieve or satisfy with liquid, so unquenchably would be with the inability to be relieved or satisfied with liquid.

**[greedily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greedy)**

- which can apply equally to food or drink: "having a strong desire for food or drink".

"drank greedily" has a number of hits on [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drank%20greedily%22&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA533CA533&oq=%22drank%20greedily%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7437j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22drank%20greedily%22&tbm=bks) - and is at least once [paired with eating ravenously](http://books.google.de/books?id=ojpGx2JgpMYC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22drank%20greedily%22&source=bl&ots=xVxegNvWXt&sig=zKqhXnig5HTNamQ35gR1geIsSko&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5DczU8zzNMHUtAas9oGwBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22drank%20greedily%22&f=false):

> Inside he found the food and water his body craved; he **ate ravenously**
>   and **drank greedily**.

Comment: As someone familiar with Latin, *voraciously* strikes me as just incorrect when applied to drinking rather than eating. While it may be "akin to" words in other languages that have to do with drinking, it itself comes from *vorare* which definitely doesn't.

Comment: I'd add to that **gushingly.** *To flow forth suddenly in great volume: water gushing from a hydrant.*

Answer (score 30):

Agree with "parchedly," but that's a pretty sorry word! You may be better off using a different verb than "to drink": gulp or guzzle, or, taking considerable poetic license with the meaning of the words, gasp or croak ("he gasped / croaked down a liter of water"). Another alternative is to use an adverb not specifically meaning "thirstily" but implying intensity or earnestness ("he desperately / furiously drank...").

Comment: I was thinking of looking for a synonym of "desperately" myself, actually.

Comment: This is a good answer to perhaps what the question should have been.

Comment: "Desperately" was my best attempt as well.

Comment: +1 for `gasp` - maybe it's more of a British thing...I don't know...

Comment: whats wrong with **thirstily** http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thirstily

Comment: Depending on context, **gulp** is what I'd pick. Though @Jodrell maybe the best of both worlds: "She thirstily gulped..."

Comment: I like “gulped desperately” too.

Answer (score 17):

The most common adverbs are ***greedily*** and ***eagerly***, and it is also  evident from various Google Ngram results<sup>**1**</sup>. Here are the *OED* definitions:

> **greedily:** As one that is hungry or thirsty; with keen appetite; hungrily, ravenously, voraciously. 
> **eagerly:** In an eager manner; with impatient desire, promptitude, or alacrity.

Some other adverbs to consider are ***gulpingly*** and ***guzzlingly***, and they are more closely associated with drinking. Here are the definitions of the verbs *gulp* and *guzzle* from *[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guzzle)*:

> **guzzle:** to drink quickly, eagerly, and usually in large amounts 
> **gulp:** to eat or drink food or liquid quickly by swallowing it in large amounts

Coincidentally, I've found an example where both adverbs are used in the same sentence for emphasis:

> Eddie picked up the former jamjar of murky water from my end of the table and drank it, gulpingly, guzzlingly. 
> <sub>*[Pompey: A Novel (by Jonathan Meades)](https://books.google.es/books?id=BF8uCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT246&dq=guzzlingly&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKgsv23Kb5AhUIbRoKHXC6DqoQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=guzzlingly&f=false)*</sub>

---

**1** I've searched various relevant and probable structures with an adverb wildcard in Google Ngram Viewer, and  *greedily* and *eagerly* came up as the most common adverbs for the context. Here are the results with screenshots:

- [Google Ngram / drank water **adverb*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drank+water+*_ADV&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)
- [Google Ngram / drank it **adverb*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drank+it+%2A_ADV&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdrank%20it%20%2A_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20slowly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20eagerly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20greedily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20quickly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20together_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20round_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20anyway_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20gratefully_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20freely_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20hastily_ADV%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cdrank%20it%20*_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20slowly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20eagerly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20greedily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20quickly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20together_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20round_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20anyway_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20gratefully_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20freely_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdrank%20it%20hastily_ADV%3B%2Cc0)
- [Google Ngram / **adverb* drank it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_ADV+drank+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnever_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthen_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Balways_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bonly_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjust_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Busually_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beagerly_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bever_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bseldom_ADV%20drank%20it%3B%2Cc0)
- [Google Ngram / **adverb* drank the](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_ADV+drank+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthen_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfirst_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bever_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnever_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Balso_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bonly_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Boften_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beagerly_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreedily_ADV%20drank%20the%3B%2Cc0)
- [Google Ngram / **adverb* gulped the](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_ADV+gulped+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthen_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquickly_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beagerly_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreedily_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhastily_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgratefully_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhurriedly_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjust_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfinally_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Balmost_ADV%20gulped%20the%3B%2Cc0)
- [Google Ngram / **adverb* gulped it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_ADV+gulped+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthen_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhere_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bimmediately_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquickly_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhastily_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjust_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreedily_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beagerly_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfinally_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgratefully_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthen_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhere_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bimmediately_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquickly_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhastily_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjust_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgreedily_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beagerly_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfinally_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgratefully_ADV%20gulped%20it%3B%2Cc0)
- [Google Ngram / gulped it **adverb*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gulped+it+%2A_ADV&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cgulped%20it%20%2A_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20back_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20greedily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20gratefully_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20quickly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20thirstily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20eagerly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20right_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20hastily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20straight_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20noisily_ADV%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cgulped%20it%20*_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20back_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20greedily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20gratefully_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20quickly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20thirstily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20eagerly_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20right_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20hastily_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20straight_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgulped%20it%20noisily_ADV%3B%2Cc0)

[image] [image]  [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Also, I'd risk gurgulingly.

Answer (score 8):

Thirstily, the adverb for thirsty.

Comment: Isn't thirstily equivalent of hungrily? I'm not sure if it is much more severe.

Comment: "Thirstily" is in the same ballpark, but I was looking for a more emphatic word.

Answer (score 7):

Parched is the best I have.

In tone it seems a bit more understated than ravenous, but I'm not aware of any others more severe.

Comment: "Parched" describes the degree of thirst being quenched, whereas "ravenously" describes the manner of eating. But I can't think of anything better, either!

Comment: Parched is an excellent answer but it is not an adverb unfortunately. And in my opinion, it does not make much sense if you say "drink parchedly".

Comment: I could concur.  I would strongly advise sentence rewrite to avoid the abomination 'parchedly'.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a note from John's answer: you'd probably want to use a combination of intense adjectives & adverbs. My suggestion would be something like "he desperately quaffed".

Comment: "Quaffed" makes me think of waffles and whiffle balls.

Comment: "Quaffed" makes me think of quickly drinking some sort of elixir or tonic, or maybe an alcoholic drink.  I'm not sure it fits here with a larger quantity of liquid.

Answer (score 3):

To describe that way of drinking you can also use the word "ravenously".

Comment: I'd go with that as well if there's nothing better, but I would have preferred something that carried less connotation of foody hunger, which is why I asked.

Comment: In that case "greedily" is also an option, but "ravenously" sounds better to me.

Answer (score 3):

How about avidly (referring to the drinker's thirst) or copiously (referring to the volume drunk)?

Comment: +1 I can read those without feeling the author is trying too hard.

Answer (score 3):

Greedily (or insatiably) might be indeed be good answers. Often, "ravenously" describes how someone eats as much as from what cause the manner of their eating proceeds. Thus, to fill in the gap:

```
He drank the water ....
```

analogously to:

```
He ate the food ravenously.
```

you could use **compulsively**, **wildly**, **with abandon**, **immoderately**, **urgently** or **obsessively**.

If you want (something like) a Tom Swifty, you could use "distraughtly". :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct counterpart that is in typical usage.  Use any word that suggests desperation or urgency, if you must use an adverb.  Describing the way the person drank visually would probably be far more descriptive, however. For example: "The traveler sank to her knees, grabbed the jug with both hands, drank the entire contents in one messy draft."

Actually, I would like to add that *ravenous* is not necessarily a term just for hunger; *a ravenous thirst* is a perfectly acceptable phrase.  *Ravenously* also means greedily or in a predatory manner; it is literally derived from the word *raven* (like the bird).  Thanks OED.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the many answers that choosing a different verb is better-suited in this case to convey the desired nuances. I particularly like "**to quaff**," which I picture as a very hasty (and messy) kind of drinking, imho fitting of the desired adverb "ravenously".

Depending on the mood of the drinker, I would go with "he quaffed recklessly/madly/aggressively" or "he quaffed heartily/vigorously"

Ps. This is more of a comment to @DanTheGameMan's answer, but alas, I don't have enough reputation for this yet.

Pps. As a non-native English speaker, I was introduced to the word by reading Terry Pratchett, where it appeared in the context of dwarfish drinking behaviour (if memory serves).

Answer (score 2):

You could also get creative with watery words and make some adjectives up, if you're into that sort of thing:

- they drank gushingly (from gushing)
- she drank oceanically (from oceanic)
- he drank flowingly (from flowing)
- she drank floodingly (from flooding)
- she drank tidingly (from tiding)
- he drank lakedly (from lake)
- they drank shoringly (from shore)
- I drank splashingly (from splash)
- we drank hydrantly (from hydrant)
- she drank drowningly (from drowning)

Some of them are groan-worthy, but I like a couple.

Answer (score 1):

The etymology of **ravenous** according to the OED: 
Originally: (of an animal) given to seizing other animals as prey; predatory; ferocious. Later: (of an animal or person; also of the appetite, hunger, etc.) voracious, gluttonous. Also fig. and in extended use.

A synonym would be 'voraciously'. So in order to answer this question one has to think of an animal which drinks voraciously. Could that be a camel, or a dog, let's say. And how does a dog drink? It 'laps' the water.

So the verb must surely be 'he lapped the liquid down him'. As for an adverb, it would have to be: **'He drank lappedly'**

Comment: That’s not true about the origin of *ravenous*: what you have stated is a mere folk etymology for which I can discover no evidence. The (surface?) evidence is that *ravenous* is not related to *raven* at all: **think *raptor* not *raven* here.** The common word *raven* for the bird *Corvus corax* comes from OE *hræfn*. *Ravenous* in contrast derives from medieval French *ravine* or medieval Latin *rapine*, both ultimately from Latin *rapere* meaning to seize and whence we also derive our own word *rape*. Whether there is a PIE link between these, however, I’ve no idea; I suppose it’s possible.

Comment: Looking further back, apparently there was a Proto-Germanic **khrabanas* for *raven*, cognate with *corvus, corax, κοραξ*, and almost surely unrelated to *rapere/rapio* where we get our own *ravenous* and *rapacious* (amongst many others).

Comment: @tchrist. This is what the OED says. It was only my presumption that it was a raven. Etymology:  < ravin n.1 + -ous suffix. Compare Old French ravineux, ravinos, rabinos rapid, impetuous (late 12th cent.). 
 (a) Originally: (of an animal) given to seizing other animals as prey; predatory; ferocious. Later: (of an animal or person; also of the appetite, hunger, etc.) voracious, gluttonous. Also fig. and in extended use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "guzzled". Or a metaphor.

He drank like a particularly parched fish who'd just been on a camel ride with the hotel holiday resort and hadn't brought any change, where the only available water was for sale by grinning tour guides.

or

He wearily examined the (beverage, water?) to check it wasn't a mirage, and once certain, with a wave of relief guzzled it down barely taking the time to breathe. Occasionally he spluttered for air, like a surfacing whale, and then returned to desperately trying to take in his own body weight in liquid.

Answer (score 0):

How about some derivative of drench? Since parched speaks of the absence of fluid, and ravenous more of the actual present consumption of food, I would think drenched (or drenchedly/drenchally if there exist such words) would be better...as it speaks more of the present consumption of and saturation with fluid.

Answer (score 0):

*drouthy* (scot, thirsty or dry)
*dehydrated*
*parched*

I would be more inclined to suggest *parched* as a solution, though I would personally use *drouthy*.

*Dehydrated* serves the same purpose but I'd use it to narrate more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct word is definitely: **Dehydratedly.**

Comment: Definitely that, or **thirstquenchingly**.

Answer (score 0):

For more general terms that applies to both eating and drinking you could try **gluttonously** or **hedonistically** depending on the connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Not an adjective, but to *slake your thirst* generally means you have been very thirsty and dehydrated