# hungry is to starving as thirsty is to?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When someone is very hungry we say he is starving. How to describe someone who is very thirsty?

Comment: Dying of thirst.

Comment: In case someone was wondering, I voted for this question to be migrated to ELL ([English Language for Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)) it would have been more helpful there than it is here IMHO.

Comment: [This was actually already answered on ELL.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29186/if-im-extremely-hungry-im-famished-if-im-extremely-thirsty-im)

Comment: 'Parched' is given in lists of synonyms, and ELU standards require that people know it is an extreme adjective.

Comment: Related: [(77770)](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77770/13162)

Answer (score 57):

*Hungry* is to *starving* as *thirsty* is to *parched*.

> **Parched**
>   : very thirsty - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parched)

Comment: Fairly rare in the US, and more apt to be used with a wink when someone wants an alcoholic beverage.  "Dying of thirst" is far more idiomatic.

Comment: But not uncommon in the UK, where context is important in distinguishing real thirst and thirst for alcohol.

Comment: My first thought was "parched" , I thought it was a common US word. Perhaps your circle of friends is just well hydrated?

Comment: @HotLicks people say "I'm starving" a lot more often than they die from lack of food; there should be room for a liquid equivalent term meaning "more than thirsty" but not going as far as "death from dehydration", shouldn't there?. (I think *parched* is a good word for the informal way people use 'starving', in the UK).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Except the "dying of thirst" typically isn't literal. I've heard that phrase many times, and no one ever meant it as they were actually about to die.

Comment: @Carcigenicate What, do you think the deaths were incidental?

Comment: @PyRulez Who died?

Comment: "Parched" or "dying of thirst" are both reasonable. I would prefer "parched" in general use, but "dying of thirst" shares the same desperately exaggerated quality of "starving", so it might be a better match in some circumstances.

Comment: As someone in the desert of Arizona, "parched" would be an accepted phrasing around here.

Answer (score 11):

While *"dying of thirst"* is still a common expression, nowadays it's much more likely to hear someone say they're ***dehydrated***. (US English)

Comment: I would say "dehydrated" is more like "malnourished." It's much more technical.

Comment: I suspect it depends a lot on where you are.  If you're running a relief station for a marathon, eg, "dehydrated" would be fairly common.  But at a refreshment stand at a county fair it would be far rarer.

Comment: "Starving" describes a current state - right now, I am starving. "Dehydrated" describes a longer-term condition - "I am generally dehydrated". You can stop being starving by eating a sandwich,  but you can't stop being dehydrated by drinking a glass of water. "Dehydrated" would be analogous to "malnourished" (you can change either condition by changing long-term habits, not by any immediate action)

Comment: If we are going to be using the base verb of "dehydrate", it should at least be "dehydrating"

Comment: And you can't stop being starved by eating something... Your body needs time to absorb the nutriment, just as it needs time to fully absorb water. If anything the effect of water against hydration is more immediate than that of food against starvation.

Comment: @JonKiparsky,JFA, et.al.- Your logic not withstanding, recent pushes in society for health-consciousness have made "I feel dehydrated", "I need to hydrate", "I'm TOTALLY dehydrated", etc., very common parlance. Don't shoot the messenger. (US)

Answer (score 3):

*Hungry is to starving as thirsty is to [**thirsting**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22thirsting+dogs%22&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilucWW69HKAhVD7BQKHb8vDdsQ_AUIDCgG)*

> assoiffé *adj* (qui a très soif)  thirsty, thirsting *adj*
>
> Il fait très chaud, les animaux sont assoiffés.
>   *It's very hot, the animals are very thirsty*.
>   [WordReference (Oxford) English-French Dictionary](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/assoiff%C3%A9)
>
> "thirsting animals" [**Google Books**](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22thirsting+animals%22&oq=%22thirsting+animals%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...9747.14544.0.15390.10.10.0.0.0.0.287.1708.0j2j6.8.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..2.0.0.3jxZk_vIT3Q)
>
> "thirsting rats" [**Google Books**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22thirsting+rats%22&lr=lang_en&biw=505&bih=332&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=BymtVoPmPMv4UPW9oOgO&start=0&sa=N&dpr=2)

Comment: All this talk of food has me all starvy.

Comment: Never heard the word thirsting.

Comment: I have heard "thirsting", but only in the phrase "thirsting for <something>"

Comment: I don't think this is accurate at all. I think you have to be thirsting for something. The quote also doesn't support this assertion because it is mostly in french.

Comment: I'm thirsting for french fries.

Answer (score 0):

The word we use here (UK) is **gasping**

> **gasp**
>
> 1.3 **(be gasping for)** *British informal* Be desperate to obtain or consume; crave:
>
> *'I'm gasping for a drink!'*
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gasp
>
> **gasping**
>
> Adjective. British. Spoken.
>
> 1. very thirsty
>
> http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gasping
>
> **be gasping**
>
> UK informal
>
> to be very ​thirsty
>
> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-gasping

It is very common for us to use "gasping" to mean "very thirsty", and, in my house, 'gasping' was used exactly like 'starving'. So I might get home from a jog on a summer's day and say,

"Oooooh, could you get me a drink, please, I'm gasping!"

However, I have only just now learned that this is peculiar to informal British usage.

Comment: Yeah.  Someone in the US might figure out what you mean, but I've never actually heard it used.

Comment: The example/definition doesn't clearly indicate thirstiness. In the US, if I hear "I'm dying for a drink" I will probably think that person wants alcohol rather than water.  Is gasping commonly used for things like water/juice?

Comment: @Kimball, no it doesn't indicate thirstiness exclusively, although I think the example and definition both point to the fact that it can be used very happily to indicate a desperate need for a drink. However, for me, certainly, it would be absolutely natural to use "gasping" exactly like "starving" (e.g., I get home after a jog on a summer's day and I say, "oooh get me a drink, please, I'm gasping"), but I couldn't find a reference for that initially. I have one now though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that often *starving* is used in a hyperbolic sense, and not its literal meaning that indicates malnourishment.

eg.

> Man I'm starving! I haven't eaten since breakfast!

The equivilent I would suggest here is *parched*.

> Man I'm parched! Do you have any water?

If you are looking for a equivilent term to the literal starving:

eg.

> The man was found starving in the desert.

I would suggest [very] dehydrated:

> The man was found critically dehydrated in the desert.
>
> The man was found severely dehydrated in the desert.

Though parched seems to still fit:

> The man was found parched in the desert.

Answer (score -1):

Hungry is to starvation as Thirsty is to "Dehydration'