# A word that means "to deprive someone of water"

Tags: single-word-requests

"to starve" means "to deprive someone of food", but what about an analogous word for water?

Is there a word that means "to deprive someone of water"?

"Dehydrate" is the closest I could think of, but its meaning is more to actively extract water, rather than withhold it. I was hoping for a word that conveyed "water" and only water - ie particular to the deprivation of water (alone)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77770/term-for-death-by-lack-of-water. Also, *dehydrate* does not necessarily mean to *actively* extract water. It just means "cause to lose water," which happens during withholding. Such strings sound fine: "The torturers were vicious. They starved him. They dehydrated him. They made him watch daytime TV."

Comment: @sil disagree. "they dehydrated him" to me means "they put him in a hot dry room for hours", rather than just "not providing water"

Comment: I'd probably go with, "they ***denied him water***"  The daytime TV thing sounds pretty mean as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster does have a closer definition than you have mentioned for **"Dehydrate:**

> 2:  to deprive of vitality or savor

"Vitality" here could very easily refer to water, depending on context.

Also, there is a medical definition of **"Desiccate"** which means according to MW:

> to dry up or cause to dry up :  *deprive or exhaust of moisture;*

or the less active, non-medical definition:

> 1:  to dry up

Comment: Neither of these are a good analogy for "starve", in my opinion: they're too "physical", rather than biological:  something that happens in the freeze-drying process, for example, rather than something that is done to a person to make them uncomfortable (or ultimately kill them).  This does feel like a "missing word", though.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you can actually be "[starved](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/starved)" of things other than food...

> 1. To suffer or die from extreme or prolonged lack of food.
> 2. Informal To be hungry.
> 3. To suffer from deprivation: *a puppy starving for attention.*

"Starved for attention" as in the third definition above, or "starved of oxygen" for example.

So, as in [this article](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/1-8-dying-patients-starved-7813363), they use "starved of water" to mean being deprived of water:

> One in eight dying patients are starved of food and water in their final days of NHS care.

And [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1250073952) uses "water-starved" as part of its title... surely a book about being starved of water would have found an official word if there were one:

> Let There Be Water: Israel's Solution for a Water-Starved World

So, for the sake of your request, it seems like "water-starved" is a good choice.

Comment: But this is hardly a common usage.

Comment: If there were a common usage, this question would likely not exist... doesn't make the answer wrong or bad. It's also inherently instantly understandable, which would not be the case with a word that is exactly what the OP wants but used by no one.

Comment: +1 Starved is used metaphorically for deprivation. Both "starved of oxygen", but also "starved of attention" are both absolutely common place expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Another word is "**parch**" which Google defines as "make or become dry through intense heat"

Answer (score 0):

When I was born, my mother's mom or her sister had not heard from her. They came to the house, and found me in a crib, and my mother just sitting in a chair. Lucky for me they recognized something was wrong. They called Dr. Vidt. He came to the house, and had to rehydrate me intravenously. My Nan told me I did not cry tears for two yrs. Insofar as I am concerned, she had 'starved me of water.' So you see, it can be done.