# "Fasting" a word for going without food, what is the equivalent for going without water?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does English have a word for voluntarily abstaining from water, like "fasting" for voluntarily abstaining from food?

Comment: Try *dehydrating* and, after that, *dying*.

Comment: I’m sure this is a duplicate. Let me look.

Comment: I've edited to include "voluntary" to try to distinguish from https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334601/a-word-that-means-to-deprive-someone-of-water, not to say its not a duplicate of some other one...

Comment: Inebriation, depending on what one substitutes for water.

Comment: W. C. Fields would have called it simple common sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asked

> Does English have a word for voluntarily abstaining from water, like "fasting" for voluntarily abstaining from food?

If a person eats food but does not drink any fluids, they are still consuming water in the foods they eat; fruit, vegetables, and some meats have a very high water content. ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908954/table/T1/))

If the person voluntarily abstains from eating food and drinking any fluids, that is within the definition of fasting.

> **Fasting**
>
> Fasting is primarily the act of willingly **abstaining from some or all food, drink, or both,** for a period of time. A fast may be total or partial concerning that from which one fasts, and may be prolonged or intermittent as to the period of fasting.
>
> Wikipedia, [Abstinence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstinence#Food)

As the term fasting is a fairly broad term, a more precise expression that describes abstaining from all food and fluids (including water) would be an **[absolute fast](https://books.google.it/books?id=VcOsKQNgfakC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22absolute%20fast%22%20definition&source=bl&ots=jNwZ_V-Y1t&sig=ACfU3U3_WsUskaqC2wF7G0QduRNegPUNkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3upKuqMriAhWEEVAKHSKvApw4FBDoATABegQIEhAB#v=onepage&q=%22absolute%20fast%22%20definition&f=false)** or **dry fasting**, or **[ta'anit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27anit)** (a Hebrew fast).

If someone refuses to eat for political or personal reasons that is a [“hunger strike”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hunger-strike); this form of protest may also include the refusal to drink fluids.